# How to change/update Dynamics crm entity record data and state from Active to Inactive with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have issues with changing the state, status and additional data for  Entity Record (Dynamics CRM 2015). 
. I am trying to update the data in just created Entity record. 
But all the time I get Bad Request. Please help me!?

this is my code.

> - Entity name: "Send Email Campaign"
> - Entity Schema Name: "concep_emailcampaign"
> - Record test name: 19/05/17-2

```js
function CreateInactiveEmailCampaign(data) { 

    var emailcampaignId, EmailCampaignName;
    var context = Xrm.Page.context; 
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl(); 
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
    var CRMObject = new Object(); 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Specify the ODATA entity collection 
    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/concep_emailcampaignSet"; 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    CRMObject.concep_name               = data.Name; 
    EmailCampaignName                   = data.Name;
    CRMObject.concep_Subject            = data.Subject;
    CRMObject.concep_SentDateTime   = data.sentdatetime;  
    CRMObject.concep_Recipients   = data.recipientsCount; 
    CRMObject.concep_CampaignID   = data.CampaignID;  
    CRMObject.concep_CampaignCode   = data.CampaignCode;     
    
    //Parse the entity object into JSON 
    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(CRMObject); 
    //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData 
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        datatype: "json", 
        url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection, 
        data: jsonEntity, 
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { 
            //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON. 
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        }, 
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) { 
            //alert("success"); 
            debugger;
            var NewCRMRecordCreated = data["d"]; 
            ChangeRecordStatus(NewCRMRecordCreated, 1, 2, serverUrl); 
        }, 
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("failure"); 
        } 
    }); 
}
function ChangeRecordStatus(data, stateCode, statusCode, serverUrl) {
 // I need to update the record with
    //CRMObject.statecode    = {}
    //CRMObject.statecode.Value   = 1;    //Inactive
    //CRMObject.statuscode    = {Value:2}
    //CRMObject.statuscode.Value  = 2;    //Inactive
    //CRMObject.concep_Campaign   = {}
    //CRMObject.concep_Campaign.Id   = data.Campaign;  
    //CRMObject.concep_SendAccount  = {}
    //CRMObject.concep_SendAccount.Id  = data.SendAccount;  
    //CRMObject.concep_SendAccount.LogicalName  = data.SendAccount;
    //CRMObject.concep_SendAccount.Name  = data.SendAccount;
    //CRMObject.concep_ResponsesTotal = ''
    //CRMObject.concep_ResponsesToRecipientsRate = ''
    //CRMObject.concep_concep_emailcampaign_list = ''
    //CRMObject.concep_emailcampaign_campaign. = ''
    //CRMObject.concep_emailcampaign_sendaccount. = ''
    //CRMObject.concep_surveyresponse_emailcampaign. = ''
    //CRMObject.user_concep_emailcampaign. = ''
 var serverUrl = serverUrl;
 var RECORD_ID = data.concep_emailcampaignId
 var EntityLogicalName = data.concep_name;
   var request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    request += "<s:Body>";
    request += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    request += "<request i:type=\"b:SetStateRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    request += "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>EntityMoniker</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    request += "<a:Id>" + RECORD_ID + "</a:Id>";
    //request += "<a:LogicalName>" + EntityLogicalName + "</a:LogicalName>";
    request += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>State</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>" + stateCode + "</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>Status</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>" + statusCode + "</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "</a:Parameters>";
    request += "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "<a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>";
    request += "</request>";
    request += "</Execute>";
    request += "</s:Body>";
    request += "</s:Envelope>";
    //send set state request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "xml",
        url:  serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web",
        data: request,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(XMLHttpRequest);
             alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

This may help: [Active/Deactive Record using JS in CRM](http://mehmetgunen.com/activate-deactivate-record-using-javascript-in-crm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a wrong Values that I sent to dynamics. In Microsoft Support page are set wrong values.

```
  var request = "" +
    "<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
    "    <s:Header>" +
    "        <SdkClientVersion xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'></SdkClientVersion>" +
    "    </s:Header>" +
    "    <s:Body>" +
    "        <Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>" +
    "            <request i:type='b:SetStateRequest' xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts'>" +
    "                <a:Parameters xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic'>" +
    "                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                        <b:key>EntityMoniker</b:key>" +
    "                        <b:value i:type='a:EntityReference'>" +
    "                            <a:Id>" + RECORD_ID + "</a:Id>" +
    "                            <a:LogicalName>concep_emailcampaign</a:LogicalName>" +
    "                        </b:value>" +
    "                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                        <b:key>State</b:key>" +
    "                        <b:value i:type='a:OptionSetValue'>" +
    "                            <a:Value>1</a:Value>" +   //<----------
    "                        </b:value>" +
    "                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                        <b:key>Status</b:key>" +
    "                        <b:value i:type='a:OptionSetValue'>" +
    "                            <a:Value>-1</a:Value>" +   //<----------
    "                        </b:value>" +
    "                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                        <b:key>MaintainLegacyAppServerBehavior</b:key>" +
    "                        <b:value i:type='c:boolean' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>true</b:value>" +
    "                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
    "                </a:Parameters>" +
    "                <a:RequestId i:nil='true' />" +
    "                <a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>" +
    "            </request>" +
    "        </Execute>" +
    "    </s:Body>" +
    "</s:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know why you are using this approach - any specific reason? Bcoz, this can be achieved easily in UI workflow with no code.

Another approach you are doing now using JS. But from where you are calling this method - CreateInactiveEmailCampaign? On form load? or ribbon click?

You have to check the form type for update mode (refer: https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/get-form-types-and-modes-in-dynamics-crm-2013/). Otherwise create mode wont have RecordId.

Debug & see which line you are getting error.

Comment: We are creating a "Send Email Campaign" that`s work fine, but now we need to create an Inactive copy of the original in the same time when we are creating /Sending/ the original. The copy needs to be available for update at any time. 

I start with this approach because I don`t have access to UI and for Xrm.Page data at all. I need to do it from JS. Back-End is not an option too.